# macbook pro mid 2012 hard drive upgrade to SSD SATA recommendation

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd, hardware-recommendation, sata

I want to upgrade my MacBook pro mid 2012 Hard disk to 512 SSD, I opened my MacBook back and took photo see below.

[image]

and then I found this on website with the following spec,

[image]
the size of my hard drive is 2.5 inch and 9.5 mm which is currently inside my MacBook, the below picture is of the one I am thinking to buy its also SSD SATA and 2.5 inch 7mm.

I am not an hardware expert, please recommend 512 SSD SATA is also very expensive.
So I will order if it will fit in my MacBook and good one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any quality ssd would be fine, I've had great luck with Samsung 850/860.  Don't worry about mm size all are 7mm and will fit..Be sure to remove the silver studs on old HHD and 
reinstall on your new SSD..  Ifixit.com has great tutorials..

it is really easy on a mid-2012 MBP

Good luck
PS While you have it open you may want to upgrade ram, replace battery and or fan.

Comment: I am definitely upgrading RAM, but I have no clue about how to upgrade fan or replace battery..

Comment: Actually don't worry about the fan. Battery only if it doesn't last as long as it used to, and it's a problem. However buy a can of canned air (BestBuy, Office Depot) and blow out the dust when you have it open. BTW **NEVER** use a vacuum cleaner on blow for this, that blows out dirt, canned air is *clean*